# Delete function for dynamic imagebutton

Tags: asp.net, button, methods, model

I am creating a dynamic ImageButton and hanging a method on it.
By clicking on this ImageButton my method should delete a product. Вut nothing happens when the button is pressed. Where in this "chain" the error occurred?
There are no errors in the developer console in the browser (F12).
P.S. I use .NET Framework 4.8, EntityFramework 6

Dynamic ImageButton:

```
ImageButton lnkDelete = new ImageButton
{
    ID = "del" + cart.ID,
    ...
};
   //OnClick Event
   lnkDelete.Click += Delete_Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you:

1 Create this dynamic control/button during each request (usually, the Page_Init, or wherever you are),

2 Insert this button into a control hierarchy after assigning the ID, but before the subscribing the event handler(s):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ImageButton lnkDelete = new ImageButton { 
        ID = "del" + cart.ID
        ...
    };

    Form.Controls.Add(lnkDelete); // <<--

    lnkDelete.Click += Delete_Item;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! On your first point: yes this dynamic imagebutton is creating during each request 2) I insert this imagebutton into a control after assigning the ID, but before the subscribing the  event. But not work yet

Comment: I insert imagebutton into Page_Load

Comment: Try to move to Page_Init. Show more your relevant code.

Comment: I tried to use Page_Init, but not work yet. I think the problem is in some missing packages, how do you think?

Comment: The same code works on another computer with VS 2013 .Net Framework V4.5, but not work at VS 2019 .Net Framework V4.8

Comment: Thank you, solved this problem by updating packages.config file, 
before that I manually changed .NET Framework from 4.5